# I want to add border line by CSS in lookup field in CPQ Quote line editor?

Tags: cpq

I am working in SFDC CPQ. When I navigate to Quote->Quote Line Editor I can see there are 5 lookup fields in the drawer. Business users are expecting an red Border in those lookup filer CPQ Quote line editor?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the appearance of the Quote Line Editor, you should use a [Custom theme](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cpq_theming_28_task.htm&type=5).

These are your options for drawers:
[image]

Comment: Hi brezotom, I have applyed genaral themes for Quote object Records view. here my requirement is i want to divide Quote records and Quote line field sets (Standard line item Drawer) using Theme in CPQ.
 how to apply theme for Quote line field sets (Standard line item Drawer) .